# Union and With Clause SubQuery Oracle

Tags: oracle, subquery

I need immediate help in solving my problem before using in production:

Am using below SQL in Oracle11g

```
With sub_query1 as (select t1.column1, t2.column2, t1.id from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id )
SELECT t3.column3 s1.* FROM sub_query1 s1 
INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.id=s1.id
union
SELECT t4.column4 s1.* FROM sub_query1 s1 
INNER JOIN table4 t4 ON t4.id=s1.id;
```

***This was working when I was using as is, but when add one subquery before SUB_QUERY1  it is not working, it is just returning 0 rows without any error***:

```
With 
main_sub_query as (select ta.id from tableA ta)
--second subquery
, sub_query1 as (select t1.column1, t2.column2, t1.id from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id 
inner join main_sub_query mq ON mq.id=t1.id
)
SELECT t3.column3 s1.* FROM sub_query1 s1 
INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.id=s1.id
union
SELECT t4.column4 s1.* FROM sub_query1 s1 
INNER JOIN table4 t4 ON t4.id=s1.id;
```

**When I remove the union and later part it is returning data, not sure what is the issue.**

Comment: "Immediate help before using in production" has no place on a public web site with unpaid volunteers. If you need immediate help with a production problem, (1) ask a competent employee of your organization; (2) ask Oracle; (3) hire a consultant.

Comment: If you want help with your code, you need to post your code - not some arbitrary (and obviously incorrect) simplification and alteration of it. Why obviously incorrect? Because you left out the comma after `t3.column3` and also after `t4.column4`. OK, we know that is not the mistake in the actual query (if you are telling the truth that it executes without errors), but that doesn't give me confidence that the rest of what you said is 100% accurate. If you need help with the actual query, then post the actual query.